# Why do browsers lose the session if we use a dot in the PHP session_name?

Tags: php

Can anyone explain to me why the browser loses the session if we use a dot (.) in the session_name?

Example:

```
session_name('abc'); // works        
session_name('a.bc'); // doesn't work
```

Comment: Can't have a period in a cookie name. Only special characters allowed are _ and -. The rest must be letters and numbers.

Comment: [_"Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores"_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Comment: See also [Session name with . or \[ silently fails instead of giving warning/error · Issue #9932 · php/php-src](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/9932)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From PHP `session_name()` docs:

> The session name references the name of the session, which is used in cookies and URLs (e.g. PHPSESSID). It should contain only alphanumeric characters; it should be short and descriptive (i.e. for users with enabled cookie warnings). If name is specified, the name of the current session is changed to its value.

Note "It should contain only alphanumeric characters".

Answer (score 2):

The [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/session_name) state that the `$name` given to `session_name($name)`

```
should contain only alphanumeric characters;
```

Thus, a new session name is generated when the one you give it is invalid.